# Assembly.Load() or Not?

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-assembly

we have a very old windows program which developed with c# and with every new publishment the customers need to reinstall the program's new version. I wonder that if it's possible.

1. I will store all classes into txt files
2. When program starts to run, my dispatcher class will search for related txt file and it will create the form/class with Assembly.Load on the fly.
3. Let's assume if I change something in X form, I will only revise the text file related to X form and overwrite it.

Is this possible?

Comment: Deliver bug fixes by not incrementing the [AssemblyVersion] so just a file copy is sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why txt files, you mean in source code form? Assembly.Load() is not a compiler.

This is not Java. You do not compile classes into *.class files (binary files).
An aggregate of C# classes are compiled into dll (a binary file).
Assembly.Load() only loads .NET dll.

So not possible to use Assembly.Load() directly with text files.

Comment: So is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for a whole uninstall-reinstall procedure. If you want to update the version of your app, you can simply dump the the updated EXE and DLL files in the directory and run them directly.

It might be tempting to split your application into many DLLs, each in charge of a specific form or component, but in most cases you'd be better off updating your whole application at once, to prevent compatibility problems.

If you really want seamless updates, consider using ClickOnce deployment, or some automatic update process like the (now obsolete) [Updater Application Block.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648668.aspx)